# datatables number of results from JSON

Tags: ajax, json, spring, model-view-controller, datatables

I have a pretty simple question on datatables for which I couldn't find an answer.

I'm using Spring MVC to generate a JSON, which has the following format:

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "firstName": "\u00d6sten",
      "lastName": "Dixon",
      "email": "hdixon0@forbes.com",
      "country": "Belarus",
      "ipAddress": "196.228.168.184",
      "creditCard": "060479202511002980",
      "company": "Trunyx",
      "timezone": "Atlantic\/South_Georgia",
      "iban": "LV55 ECXH IGFF GSEW YHMU G",
      "latitude": "52.644",
      "longitude": "25.2027",
      "race": "Blackfeet"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "firstName": "Agn\u00e8s",
      "lastName": "Perry",
      "email": "wperry1@blogspot.com",
      "country": null,
      "ipAddress": "75.63.229.226",
      "creditCard": "5191970963453131",
      "company": "Tanoodle",
      "timezone": "Asia\/Kabul",
      "iban": "TN75 8279 0633 7374 0209 2905",
      "latitude": "11.97444",
      "longitude": "-86.09417",
      "race": null
    },
// more
  ],
  "totalPages": 51,
  "last": false,
  "totalElements": 503,
  "size": 10,
  "number": 0,
  "sort": null,
  "numberOfElements": 10,
  "first": true
}
```

I'd like to display the result using [datatables](http://datatables.net/), however it looks like it's expecting a "iTotalRecords" for example, where my JSON has a "totalElements"

How can I specify that mapping?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#datatable').DataTable({
            "bProcessing":  true,
            "bServerSide":  true,
            "sAjaxSource":  "members",
            "sAjaxDataProp" : 'content',
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "firstName" },
                { "data": "lastName" },
                { "data": "email" },
                { "data": "country" },
                { "data": "ipAddress" },
                { "data": "creditCard" },
                { "data": "company" },
                { "data": "timezone" },
                { "data": "iban" },
                { "data": "latitude" },
                { "data": "longitude" },
                { "data": "race" },
            ]
        });
```